# Directus API : how to filter the results

Tags: php, api, directus

I want to query the Directus API for changes that have happened since I last checked.
This means hitting the [/activity endpoint](https://api.getdirectus.com/1.1/#API_Endpoints) and filtering based on the datetime param, but I can't seem to get the filter parameter to work.

I'm trying something like this *(based on [examples in the docs](https://api.getdirectus.com/1.1/#Filters))* :

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <my_token>" "https://<my_server>/api/1.1/activity/?filter[datetime][gt]=2017-06-23T01:45:18-11:00" -g`

That request succeeds, but the filter part of it has no effect.

**What is the correct syntax for the filter parameter ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter is named `filters` (plural) instead of `filter`. The rest of the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Since Directus 7, the paramteter is indeed `filter` and not `filters`